# tkinter messagebox.showinfo in thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, tkinter, queue

In python 2, when the `messagebox` appears, the thread stops and waits until I click OK. Why does a `messagebox` appear in python 3, but the thread continues to move on?
The initial thread should be queued by the tkinter element, but this does not happen.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
import threading, queue
from threading import Thread

q = queue.Queue()
sem = threading.Semaphore()

class call(Thread):
    def __init__(self, text):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.text = text
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        sem.acquire()
        a.set(self.text)
        print (self.text)
        sem.release()

class message(Thread):
    def __init__(self, text):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.text = text
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        sem.acquire()         
        start_thread(q.put(( messagebox.showinfo, ('WARNING!', self.text), {} )))     
        sem.release()

def start():
    _th34410 = call('dc1')
    _th34410 = message('ac')
    _th34410 = call('dc2')

def start_thread(fun, a=(), k={}):
    threading.Thread(target=fun, args=a, kwargs=k).start()

def tkloop():
    try:
        while True:
            f, a, k = q.get_nowait()
            f(*a, **k)
    except:
        pass

    root.after(100, tkloop)

root = tk.Tk()

a = tk.StringVar()

but1 = ttk.Button(root, text='Start', command=start).pack(side=tk.TOP)
entry1 = ttk.Entry(root, textvariable=a, width=10).pack(side=tk.TOP)

tkloop()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't know specifically why it worked in Python 2 but not now in Python 3. That said, generally speaking `tkinter` doesn't support multithreading in the sense that only one thread access its methods (even with mutex). You have several of threads which appear to violate this restriction — so for some unknown reason, you're apparently not getting away with doing it any longer.

Comment: What does *"but the thread continues to move on"* means? All the three threads should be started and then finished very soon since there is no loop inside `run()`.  The only running in the background is `tkloop()`, but it is not a thread.

Comment: Instead: start_thread(q.put(( messagebox.showinfo, ('WARNING!', self.text), {} ))); Past: messagebox.showinfo('WARNING!', self.text). Delete: def tkloop(): and def start_thread()